# PHP MYSQL to JSON dynamic object

Tags: php, mysql, json

[image]

This is my table and I would like to PHP to generate json like this

```
{
  "1":
  {
    "start_time":"03:27:43","end_time":"06:27:43"
  },
  "2":
  {
    "start_time":"03:27:43","end_time":"06:27:43"
  },
  "3":
  {
    "start_time":"03:27:43","end_time":"06:27:43"
  },
  "4":
  {
    "start_time":"03:27:43","end_time":"06:27:43"
  },
  "5":
  {
    "start_time":"03:27:43","end_time":"06:27:43"
  },
  "6":
  {
    "start_time":"03:27:43","end_time":"06:27:43"
  }
}
```

Not being able to put the subtopics in PHP Array, can you please help

Comment: Use table syntax instead of images. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for instructions.

Comment: It can be just from the database by fetching data and then convert into the json using json_encode. I can tell exactly without seeing your code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

If you have MySQL 5.7.22 or later, or MariaDB 10.5 or later, you can do the whole job in a single query, using the [JSON_OBJECTAGG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-objectagg) and [JSON_OBJECT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) functions.

For example, using your table above:

```
select json_objectagg(week_day, json_object('start_time',start_time, 'end_time',end_time)) as json from jsonTest;
```

will return this string:

```
{
"0": 
  {"end_time": "06:27:43.000000", "start_time": "03:27:43.000000"}, 
"1": 
  {"end_time": "06:27:43.000000", "start_time": "03:27:43.000000"}, 
"2": 
  {"end_time": "06:27:43.000000", "start_time": "03:27:43.000000"}, 
"3": 
  {"end_time": "06:27:43.000000", "start_time": "03:27:43.000000"}, 
"4": 
  {"end_time": "06:27:43.000000", "start_time": "03:27:43.000000"}, 
"5": 
  {"end_time": "06:27:43.000000", "start_time": "03:27:43.000000"}, 
"6": 
  {"end_time": "06:27:43.000000", "start_time": "03:27:43.000000"}
}
```

One query, one fetch, one value returned in the form you want. There's no need to loop over the result set to assemble the data in memory with PHP and then json_encode it - it's all done.

**Edit**
If the time format is important, [TIME_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) is your friend:

```
select json_objectagg(week_day, json_object('start_time',time_format(start_time, '%H:%i:%s'), 'end_time',time_format(end_time,'%H:%i:%s'))) as json from jsonTest;
```

Comment: This is awesome. Let me try and see if I can get rid of the 0s at the ends

Comment: @EhsanulKarim TIME_FORMAT() will sort that out. I've added an example.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer without seeing your current code but the basic steps are:

1. Pull the data from your MYSQL table - recommended to use MySql PDO as per [here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)
2. Use `json_encode()` PHP function to convert the result into JSON as per [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
3. Output the encoded JSON to wherever you need it

**Example Code**

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT start_time, end_time FROM table");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Thanks. The only thing is I dont get the object if I do this.